# SAX parser reading portion of XML element when there is unusually big value somewhere in the document

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

I have using SAX parser to read a few elements from a large XML file. Below are the sample XML and the SAX parser code i am using for this purpose.

```
<someOtherElement>231</someOtherElement>
<someMoreOtherElement>1233.00213</someMoreOtherElement>
...
<elementToRead1>31.0.1</elementToRead1>
<elementToRead2>ABCD-XYZ-1.0</elementToRead2>
```

The parser code:

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private String elementToRead1

    private Boolean flag1 = false;

    private String elementToRead2

    private Boolean flag2 = false;

    public void readValues(final String xmlString) throws XMLParseException {
        SAXXMLParser.parseString(xmlString, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName, final Attributes attributes) {

        if (""elementToRead1"".equals(qName)) {
            flag1 = true;
        }

        if (""elementToRead2"".equals(qName)) {
            flag2 = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char ch[], final int start, final int length) {
        if (flag1) {
            elementToRead1 = new String(ch.clone(), start, length);
            flag1 = false;
        }

        if (flag2) {
            elementToRead2 = new String(ch.clone(), start, length);
            flag2 = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works fine and i am getting proper values with this code. But while testing, i tried changing the value of one of the element in XML to something really long and because of the, one of the elements that i need to read in my parser started picking it up wrong. 
Suppose the problem XML is:

```
 <someOtherElement>231</someOtherElement>
<someMoreOtherElement>9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991233.00213</someMoreOtherElement>
...
<elementToRead1>31.0.1</elementToRead1>
<elementToRead1>ABCD-XYZ-1.0</elementToRead2>
```

With this kind of XML, the value for elements are always read like this:

elementToRead1 - 31.0.1

elementToRead2 - ABCD-XYZ-1

I have no idea why this second element is read wrong. I have tried using debug point and everything and i can confirm that there is no exception thrown anywhere. Only the value for second element is read wrong in case of this problem XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it's caused by the characters method called more than once for the value. You need to use a StringBuilder and append the characters in order to get the correct value, then in the endElement set the value and reset the builder.

It should work.

```
@Override
public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName, final Attributes attributes) {
    stringBuffer.setLength(0);

    if ("elementToRead1".equals(qName)) {
        flag1 = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    stringBuffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    String result = stringBuffer.toString();

    if (flag1) {
        elementToRead1 = result;
        flag1 = false;
    }
}
```

From the [docs](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters(char[],%20int,%20int)):

> SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information.

Comment: You solution works fine for me. Although you should reset the string buffer in element start method else it will read some tab characters in case of nested elements. Also, i still have no clue about exactly what cause the problem. Can you explain it a bit ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct, I've edited the answer.  It's not a problem but how the characters methd works, see edited answer!